# Is there a substance i could treat concrete with to make it not scratched by steel?

Tags: concrete

Is there a substance i could use that would harden the surface of concrete enough to make it resist scratching by steel?

Comment: It depends on the( Force/square inch) and to some degree the hardness of the steel and the hardness of concrete aggregate,

Answer (score 0):

I suggest exploring the "Dry Shake Hardeners" produced by Sika, which I consider the leader/best in cement products. https://www.sika.com/en/knowledge-hub/dry-shake-hardeners-for-concrete-floors.html#Abrasion